# React, how do I get a dashboard to route over the private routes correctly?

Tags: reactjs, routes

I have a project that has a login page, a **signup** page, a **dashboard** and a **forgot password** page.

The **login**, **signup** and **forgot password** pages all work as it is connected to google firebase and I have used react bootstrap to make it look in the way I wanted it to look.

Originally when someone signed in, they would only be greeted with their email and a “change password” button.

After that I needed to create a dashboard, so I did. The dashboard can go to wherever I like on the website, but the problem is that it wouldn’t allow me to see anything that those pages originally had.

I looked around and realized that I needed to change how the dashboard was connected to the application. Since I use routes, I thought that it would just be as easy as incapsulating the dashboard around the parts that I wanted it to function for but that didn’t work at all.
I have not been able to find another problem that looked similar so that’s why I am asking.

**App:**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Container>
        <AuthProvider>
          <Switch>
            <Dash>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/account" component={Account} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/update-profile" component={UpdateProfile} />
            </Dash>
            <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword} />
          </Switch>
        </AuthProvider>
      </Container>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

**Private Route:**

```
export default function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth()

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        return currentUser ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
      }}
    ></Route>
  )
}
```

**Dashboard:**

```
function Dash() {
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);

  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);

  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: '#fff' }}>
        <div className='navbar'>
          <Link to='#' className='menu-bars'>
            <FaIcons.FaBars onClick={showSidebar} />
          </Link>
        </div>
        <nav className={sidebar ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
          <ul className='nav-menu-items' onClick={showSidebar}>
            <li className='navbar-toggle'>
              <Link to='#' className='menu-bars'>
                <AiIcons.AiOutlineClose />
              </Link>
            </li>
            {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                  <Link to={item.path}>
                    {item.icon}
                    <span>{item.title}</span>
                  </Link>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default Dash;
```

The dashboard is named **Dash**. And, as i stated before, this doesn't work because it doesn't show the "Account" nor the "UpdateProfile" and only shows the Dash jsx.

**So my basically question is**: how do i route over these correctly? (Since i want the dashboard to be over both my profile).
And could the mix of my react-bootstrap profile and my jsx+css dashboard be the main problem as to why the profile isn't showing up?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share the code for `Dash` and `PrivateRoute`.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Did so, sorry late response.

Comment: As far as I can you, you actually aren't rendering `children`, the `PrivateRoute` components, you are passing as children to `Dash`. If they aren't rendered by `Dash` they would effectively be ignored. Maybe started by rendering `children` (prop) somewhere in `Dash`.